# complex numbers in algebraic form and operations

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

The question itself is very easy so I need only a small hint if I understand it correctly, I have to calculate:

$$\overline{(3+i)}(2-i)$$

So how to multiply them? Should I act like this?

$$\overline{(3+i)} = (3-i)$$

And then multiply them like:

$$(3-i)(2-i)$$

Using standard formula. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is $$(3-i)(2-i)=6-2i-3i-1=5(1-i)$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right. This is exactly the definition of the complex conjugate.